# C# SQL Server database update data

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to update data in a SQL Server database but something is wrong. My code does not update the database and I don't know what the problem is

```
if (d.Contains("1"))
{
    sql1 = "UPDATE Faucets SET Enabled='0' WHERE FaucetName='" + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value + "'";
}
else
{
    sql1 = "UPDATE Faucets SET Enabled='1' WHERE FaucetName='" + dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value + "'";
}

SqlConnection connect1 = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\faucets.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

connect1.Open();
SqlCommand parancs1 = connect1.CreateCommand();
parancs1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
parancs1.CommandText = sql1;

parancs1.ExecuteNonQuery();
connect1.Close();
```

Comment: did you check the content of sql1 string while debugging?

Comment: In the debugger, what is the value of `dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value`

Comment: You are looking at the right database? The one that is in your app_data\ folder of your web application?

Comment: What kind of application is this? WinForms/WPF or a web application (Important to understand the exact working for |DataDirectory|)? Is that _Enabled_ a bit column on the database (then its values are not strings) ? What is the return value from ExecuteNonQuery (if it is not zero then you have updated the value but not where you are looking for it)?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: Do you get any error message and is your Enabled filed a **CHAR** or **VARCHAR**, if not then change `Enabled = '0'` to `Enabled = 0` is assume it is an **INT** or **SMALLINT**.

Comment: Wrap you code in try/catch and debug to look at the exception message.

Comment: If You are using localDB, You should specify name of database, not attaching database